# How do i program for a mac

Tags: c, printf, max, program-entry-point

Hello,

I want to program for a mac.

I already know some program languages like c

Does this work on a mac?

```
main()
{ printf("hello world");}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Probably would be best to buy a book or search online for tutorials. There will be plenty of both.

Comment: you really need some more detail on this question? What would you like to do with your Mac programming? What areas interest you? With this info people might be able to help on this site.

Comment: Learn objective C, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use C programming language on Mac. The main programming language on Mac OS X is Objective-C, which is based on C language.

You can download Xcode from the AppStore and start developing your own application. C is perfectly fine, as it is subset of Objective-C.

I suggest you to start here: http://www.cocoalab.com/?q=becomeanxcoder it is little outdated, but you will get the basic idea.